# Limits on Sturm-Liouville derivation integrating factor

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, functions

My course notes have the following exercise:

> Show that any differential operator
>   $$
> A = p_0 (x)\frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + p_1 (x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + p_2 (x)
> $$
>   can be written in Sturm-Liouville form $(A_{SL} = \frac{1}{w(x)} \left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(p(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right) + q(x)  \right])$ by choosing
>   $$
> p(x) = \exp \left[ \int^x_a \frac{p_1(t)}{p_0(t)}  \mathrm{d}t \right],
> $$
>   $$
> w(x) = \frac{p(x)}{p_0{x}} = \frac{1}{p_0 (x)} \exp \left[ \int^x_a \frac{p_1(t)}{p_0(t)} \mathrm{d}t\right],
> $$
>   $$
> q(x) = p_2 (x) w(x).
> $$
>   where $p(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (a,b).$

My problem lies in the limits of the integrating factor in the definition of $p(x)$ - in particular, the lower limit of $a$. I have seen the definition of $p(x)$ as
$$
p(x) = \exp \left[ \int^x \frac{p_1(u)}{p_0(u)}\mathrm{d}u \right]
$$
in other texts, so I understand that the point of the lower limit is to just return zero. However, I can't see any reason that it would!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Sturm-Liouville form $\frac{1}{w(x)} \left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(p(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right) + q(x)  \right])$ we can multiply $p,q,w$ by the same constant and still get the same operator. The choice of lower limit in 
$$p(x) = \exp \left[ \int_{\text{whatever}}^x \frac{p_1(u)}{p_0(u)}\mathrm{d}u \right]$$
only contributes an additive constant, which becomes multiplicative constant after exponentiation. The same constant appears in $w$, and (through $q=p_2w$) in $q$. So at the end it does not change the operator.

I prefer to write: let $\phi$ be some antiderivative of $p_1/p_2$, then the choice $p=e^\phi$, $w=p/p_0$ and $q=wp_2$ gives $A=\frac{1}{w(x)} \left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(p(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right) + q(x)  \right])$.